get device impression of gg ads api
I want to get impression parameters of devices in advertising campaigns using gg ads api
I have read their docs a lot but can't find any results, please help me.
I tried using segments.device or  campaign_criterion.device.type but it didn't work either.
I want to get data of this screen
enter image description here
